# OpenGL ES 2.0 Android Blood decals on a plane

Tags: android, opengl-es, decal

I have a very simple game idea in mind just for myself learning OpenGL. This is a 2d game with a simple textured plane background (ortho projection). On this background some generic enemies will move and when shot they must leave a blood splatter (decal). Ideally there should be hundreds of these enemies, so after some time there will be quite many blood on the surface.

My question is how this type of decals is implemented? Any suggestions, directions? surface is planar, so I'm guessing it is a simple case. My wild guess is to somehow draw all splatters on a texture and then blend this texture with original texture on a plane, but I have no idea if this is the way to go..

Comment: At first you can start with rendering these blood splatters separately one by one (plus maybe a counter limit once they start to fade away). Later on, I'd say, preferred way would be using FBO texture for rendering them like you described and mixing this texture into background during one pass. But once you have them rendered separately pretty much the same code works for offscreen rendering too.

Comment: thank you. I'll try to play with FBOs